# What is the easiest way to customize PDF document with a serial number

Tags: windows, pdf

I have several PDF documents. Users of my Windows application want to print these PDF files. An additional requirement is to add auto incremented serial number to each printed PDF. The serial number is used for accounting purposes, not for security reasons as someone [asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5348053/embed-serial-number-to-pdf-file).

What is the easiest way to implement above functionally?

I know that I can buy commercial license of [iText](http://www.itextpdf.com/itext.php) and edit PDF files. However I would like to know if there is a simpler solution. E.g. Add a form field to PDF document, distribute it to my users, and then use some Acrobat Reader command line option to fill in the form field with serial number generated by my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PDFTK (The PDF Toolkit)](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) is a command-line app that allows you to edit PDFs with ease. For example, you could use the `update_info` command to change the meta-data, or apply a `background` (which isn't all that easy, as it requires another PDF to get the background from)...

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the FREE Quick PDF Library Lite.

QP.LoadFromFile(Filename);
QP.SetOrigin(1);   // set origin coordinate system to top right corner
QP.DrawText(10,10, mySerialNumber);
QP.SaveToFile(newFilename);

You can find more information at http://www.quickpdflibrary.com/free/lite.php

"Quick PDF Library Lite is available as an ActiveX component and works with C, C++, C#, Delphi, PHP, Visual Basic, VB.NET, ASP, PowerBASIC, Pascal or any other language that supports ActiveX."

Disclaimer : I do consulting work for the QuickPDF products.